# using different url for a file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, routes

Hello I want to change the URL of a page

at the moment it looks like

```
www.domain.com/privacy
```

and I want it to look like

> www.domain.com/privacy-policy

since it looks much better. Is there a way to achieve this in codeigniter?

Comment: you can use `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Why not just use `301 redirection` rule in your `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: Ye but then I have to rewrite this for many urls but I want to do it only for a few.

Comment: you can only for this url, maybe that: `Redirect 301 /privacy-policy http://example.com/privacy` in `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter uses the routes defined in `config/routes.php` to rewrite URLs.

Add a line like this: `$routes['privacy-policy'] = 'controller/action';`

For full documentation, read the user guide:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html